# jQuery's animate method

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I am trying to use jQuery animate method but it is not working properly.
I tried is using both self-invoked function and function declaration as well but still it's not working

```js
(function () {
  
    var links = $('.page-link');
 
    for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
      
        links[i].onclick = function () {
          
            var data = this.getAttribute('data-value')
            
            $('body').animate({
              
                scrollTop: $('.' + data).offset().top
              
            }, 800);
        };
    }
})();
```

```html
<ul id='menu-list'>
                        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" class='page-link' id='about' data-value='services'>About</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" class='page-link' data-value='team'>Team</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" class='page-link' data-value='search'>Search</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" class='page-link' data-value='contact'>Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    
                    
                    <div id="main-services" class='services'></div>
                    <div id='services-container' class='search'></div>
                    <div id='team' class='team'></div>
                    <div id='contact' class='contact'></div>
```

Comment: What HTML is it operating on? How is it loaded into the HTML? What happens if you add logging to it? What is `links.length`? Does the event handler ever fire when you click a link?

Comment: when using Jquery why are you using inline event handlers? And `this` inside a plain function would point `window`, not the clicked element.

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy — No. The value of `this` inside a function invoked as an event handler is the element to which the function is bound.

Comment: @Quentin Oh Thanks for pointing that. Let me have a clear view on that. I think I have confused myself with `... onclick="hai()" ..>` kind of code.

Comment: I've put together a test case, and that code works fine. Whatever the problem is, you haven't put enough detail in the question to show what it is.

Comment: 1) @Quentin So I have tried console.log onclick it works perfectly that means something is wrong with the animate method.

Comment: 2) @RajaprabhuAravindasamy this inside function points to the clicked element not to window object.

Comment: Your comments have ruled out one of the problems I suspected you had. I can think of another three off the top of my head. You need to provide a proper test case.

Comment: @Akash Try to do animate with double selector: $('html, body') as I explained in my answer. Body animate is used on webkit, Html animate on firefox.

Comment: @Quentin   I hope this will help you understand the problem better     [link](https://jsfiddle.net/whp1ecd4/)

Comment: Hope what will? You haven't edited the question.

Comment: @Quentin   I hope this will help you understand the problem better     [link](https://jsfiddle.net/whp1ecd4/)

Comment: @Akash — Put your test case in the question, not on an external site.

Comment: OK. It doesn't work because … the entire document is visible on screen, so when you try to scroll, there is nowhere to scroll to. (I'm putting this as a comment because I don't believe it is the answer, just that the test case is still not one which actually reflects the problem).

Answer (score -2):

Do you want to simply add an onClick function on every item with `class=page-link`?

Simply try to do this:

```
var links = $('.page-link'); 

links.on('click', function(){
    var data = $(this).attr('data-value');
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $('.' + data).offset().top
    }, 800);
});
```

Tried a bit different syntax. Also use selector 'html, body' on animate function.

Comment: That's alternative syntax which should do exactly the same thing. If the original code doesn't work, why should this?

Comment: I also add selectors on animate function. Not only body, but also html, because body is used on webkit, html on firefox.